# How to concat upcoming string and until new line occurs?

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

I'm using [elixir_serial](https://github.com/bitgamma/elixir_serial) that returns from my device chopped bitstream, how can I concat it in elixir until in `"\n"` delimiter? I found example in node.js [node-serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport/blob/master/parsers.js#L20-L23), but can't find good examples to build it in my handle_info()?

```
def init([]) do
  {:ok, serial} = Serial.start_link
  Serial.open(serial, "/dev/cu.usbserial-A5026NYN")
  Serial.set_speed(serial, 9600)
  Serial.connect(serial)
  Logger.debug "pid #{inspect serial}"

  # @key_parts = []
  {:ok, []}
end

def handle_info({:elixir_serial, serial, data}, state) do
  Logger.debug "received :data #{data}"
  {:noreply, state}
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [String.split/3](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/String.html#split/3):

```
iex(1)> String.split("foo\nbar", "\n")
["foo", "bar"]
```

You can pattern match on this to get all the data until `\n`:

```
iex(2)> [head | _tail] = String.split("foo\nbar", "\n")
["foo", "bar"]
iex(3)> head
"foo"
```

If there is no `\n` in the string then the original string will be returned in a list with 1 element.

**Edit**

To build up a list until you receive `\n` do:

```
def init(_) do
  {:ok, []}
end

def handle_info({:elixir_serial, serial, "\n"}, state) do
  #Do stuff with state - be sure to reverse state as we have been building up using `[head | tail]`
  # You can use Enum.reverse(state) for this.
  {:noreply, state}
end

def handle_info({:elixir_serial, serial, data}, state) do
  {:noreply, [data | state]}
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to push handled `data` in instance array and if `data` contains only '\n' string then return joined array and empty it, I don't know how to do that in Elixir?

Comment: How to set instance array in `init()` method?

Comment: You don't have the concept of "instance" arrays - you can store state in your GenServer though - it is the 2nd argument. The state is initially set as the return value from the `init` function as `{:ok, state}` - so you would set it with `{:ok, []}`

Comment: Thanks again, pattern match is really nice feature, could you tell me yet how to match state string until 12 chars?

Comment: @luzny you can use `byte_size` in a guard.  http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html

Comment: I've posted new related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352329/can-i-use-two-patterns-in-handle-info-and-what-is-guard-clauses-syntax-in-patt)