# What is syntax for byte_size in pattern matching?

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

How to match and what syntax is to check `byte_size` equal 12 length pattern in `handle_info()`? Can I use both patterns in `handle_info()`, eg. first that will check string for new line, second with `byte_size`?

Example code without `byte_size` pattern:

```
def init(_) do
  {:ok, []}
end

def handle_info({:elixir_serial, serial, "\n"}, state) do
  {:noreply, Enum.reverse(state)}
end

def handle_info({:elixir_serial, serial, data}, state) do
  Logger.debug "data: #{data}"
  {:noreply, [data | state]}
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use both patterns, this is the purpose of having multiple function clauses. From top to bottom, the first matching function clause will be executed.

You can use different binary patterns to match 12 bytes, depending on which output you need:

```
iex> <<data::bytes-size(12)>> = "abcdefghijkl"
"abcdefghijkl"
iex> data
"abcdefghijkl"

iex> <<data::size(96)>> = "abcdefghijkl"
"abcdefghijkl"
iex> data
30138990049255557934854335340
```

These patterns can of course be used in your function clauses:

```
def handle_info({:elixir_serial, serial, <<data::bytes-size(12)>>}, state) do
  # ...
end

def handle_info({:elixir_serial, serial, <<data::size(96)>>}, state) do
  # ...
end
```

For more info on available types and modifiers, you can look up the documentation of the bitstring syntax [online](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1) or in `iex` by typing `h <<>>`.

You could also use a guard clause together with `byte_size`:

```
def handle_info({:elixir_serial, serial, data}, state) when byte_size(data) == 12 do
  # ...
end
```

Comment: How can I concat incoming strings from : elixir_serial until state reach desired 12 length? Currently it doesn't match, data in last handle_info() contain string with different length. I've tryed with <<state::bytes-size(12)>>, but output is also wrong.

Comment: I'm saving data in place where it is Logger.debug in my code snippet, is it right place to handle matched data?

Comment: Yes that is the right place. If the data is variable in size, I would not match the length at all.